# PHP Only display fields that were submitted

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a scoring system for deer and I have a form that asks for the measurements. I also have an option that adds more forms (if the deer has more than 4 tines, or 4 abnormal points). Now when I submit my form it sends it a /add.php. I have it so it displays the original forms and then I want to make it so it shows the addition forms. BUT only if they used that form. So basically I want it to display the measurement in the fields ONLY if they were used.

```
<?php
  $a = $_GET['a'];
  $b = $_GET['b'];
  $c = $_GET['c'];
  $d = $_GET['d'];
  //....continueing on....//

  $answer = $a + $b + $c + $d + $e + $f + //....continue...//

?>
```

I have the above code in my /add.php to pull in the information from my forms.

```
<a href="#" id="link_d" onclick="new_field('file_e');hide_mais('link_d')">Add More</a>
```

The above code is to add more fields (along with a ID set in the table).

```
<input type="text" name="pp">
```

The above is an example of one of the forms that im using.

I am wanting to display the original fields (a,b,c,d,etc..) and then if someone had clicked "add more" and entered in another field. I want that field to be displayed as well (aa,bb,cc,etc...)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the deer to use a computer?

Anyway, for your question: By using [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Try this to get you started.

```
foreach( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    echo "var $key set to $value\n";
}
```

Comment: I dont know much about php, so where abouts would I need that.